# Edit Content Area Width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to expand my content area to be as big as my page, however there's something stopping it.  And I'm not quite sure what it is.  I'm using the Shapely theme.

Here's what I mean.

[image]
So, what's the way to get my image to stretch all the way to the left?

Comment: We aren't mind readers Edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste all of your code.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It's Wordpress, so I'd have to post style.css, because if I knew specifically where to find the rule to change, I wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really useful if you put down your code but I'll just answer what I think you meant.

To be able to make it stretch the whole screen. With your div, make sure the padding and margin is all set to 0 and the width and height is set to 100%.

for example:

```
.yourdiv {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```